# Javascript/jQuery fadeIn fadeOut not show after N length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Javascript/jQuery `fadeIn` `delay` and `fadeOut` for my array text.

```js
function animate(text){
    var index = 0;
    $(".text").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        index = (index + 1) % text.length;
        this.textContent = text[index];
    }).fadeIn(1000, animate);
}

var text = ['1', '2', '3'];

$(".text").text(text[0]); //First Show

animate(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text"></div>
```

That above code is only working until `2`. 3 is never display cause error like this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Is there any missing part of above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animate` takes an argument, which you're initially passing in as the array:

```
animate(text);
```

But the recursive callback isn't getting the argument:

```
}).fadeIn(1000, animate);
```

Your `index` also isn't persisting recursively.

I'd get rid of the argument and use the outer variable instead, for both `text` and `index`.

```js
var index = 0;

function animate() {
  $(".text").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    index = (index + 1) % text.length;
    this.textContent = text[index];
  }).fadeIn(1000, animate);
}

var text = ['1', '2', '3'];

$(".text").text(text[0]); //First Show

animate(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `text` as arguement in first call but when fadeout calls the functio `animate` without parameter, there  it assumes `text` as null. And the error `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"` means you are trying to find the length of a null variable.